# Splitting a string within an array:

Tags: php, arrays

If you have a multidimensional array, such as follows:

```
$array = array(
                'name' => 'user',
                'values' => 'one, two, three',
                'params' => array('three');    
                );
```

How can you split 'values' key so it then becomes an array on its own?

i.e

```
$array = array(
                'name' => 'user',
                'values' => array('one', 'two', 'three'),
                'params' => array('three');    
                );
```

Comment: Your title is misleading. Actually you have a *string* that you want to split (`'one, two, three'` is just a string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to run this check on all the fields and not just the values one:

```
foreach($array as &$value)
{
    if (!is_array($value))
    {
        $value = explode(', ', $value);
    }   
}
unset($value);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$array['values'] = explode(', ', $array['values']);
```